# How do I know if my Ordered Logistic Regression is a good model?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I have a few questions about Ordered Logistic Regression Model (OLR). In general, how do I know if this is my model is good, and how do I enhance it?

Using this example from https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/, if these are the outputs I am looking at:

```
## R OUTPUTS
## Call:
## polr(formula = apply ~ pared + public + gpa, data = dat, Hess = TRUE)

## Coefficients:
##          Value Std. Error t value
## pared   1.0477      0.266   3.942
## public -0.0588      0.298  -0.197
## gpa     0.6159      0.261   2.363
## 
## Intercepts:
##                             Value  Std. Error t value
## unlikely|somewhat likely     2.204  0.780      2.827 
## somewhat likely|very likely  4.299  0.804      5.345 
## 
## Residual Deviance: 717.02 
## AIC: 727.02


## R INPUT
exp(cbind(OR = coef(m), ci))

## R OUTPUT
##            OR  2.5 % 97.5 %
## pared  2.8511 1.6958  4.817
## public 0.9429 0.5209  1.681
## gpa    1.8514 1.1136  3.098
```

What can I do to enhance/improve my OLR model in R?  What output values should I be focusing on?

Does improving my OLR model mean looking at my P values and coefficients and removing the ones that are not statistically significant?

I am stuck as I don't really know what to do after I run the model.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do with this model?

Comment: "looking at my P values and coefficients and removing the ones that are not statistically significant" is almost never a good approach in any regression.